# What do i put in get_permalink(get_option(' here???')

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to work out what the option value is in get_permalink(get_option('jr_dashboard_page_id')  I'm trying to follow this convention but cant work where it comes from - dashboard is the post-name in the DB  what the rest of it means or how its works I cant figure out...

Any help would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Options API* stores key-value pairs. For example, `add_option( 'key', 'value' );` could be used. In that case, `get_option( 'key' );` would return `value`.

So at some point a plugin or the themes that you use defined jr_dashboard_page_id to be something. Perhaps via a meta box or something like that. There is not enough information in this question to say exactly what "key" you need. It's like saying, I have an associative array $array['key'] what key should I use? We simply can't know because we don't know how array looks and we don't know what kind of value you expect.

Comment: many thanks for your help - nice answer - I have found the key value pair in wp_options and yes it is a theme I'm working on...thanks agian